# Create Folder() Showing "<Result/>".But Folder are not getting created on Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I would like to create a folder in Sharepoint 2007 with C# using DWS Web Service.

Code:

```
dwsFolder.CreateFolder(@"Test_FormLib/myNewFolder");
```

If I use the program for the first time, I get the message:

```
<Result/>
```

No error. The second time  I get the message:

```
<Error ID="13">AlreadyExists</Error>
```

But I do not see the folder on my website.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In another clown product from Microsoft, I just spend 4 hours on this exact problem. `CreateFolder` only works properly for document libraries, not form libraries. If you're trying to write to a form library, your documents are going to show up in another folder. For me, they were showing up in 'shared documents', even though I was specifying to create a folder under 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation: [Dws.CreateFolder Method (Document Workspace)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774480.aspx):

> The following code example shows the use of the CreateFolder method to create a new subfolder in the default document library of the site. The absolute URL of the new folder is "http://server_name/sites/user_name/workspace_name/Shared Documents/folder_name".

So, you must check if you're using correct site address, under authenticated user_name.

Comment: But if i put Path in above format (as suggested by you) it is showing 

" <Error ID=“10”>FolderNotFound</Error>"

Comment: I didn't suggested that: I just suggest to check into full path: replace server_name, user_name, workspace_name for actual values and you'll probably find your new folder. I think you're checking on wrong place

Comment: i specified the desired path.

As: "sitename/Documents/newfoldername"

Folders are getting created but not on specified path but on "Style Library".

But why so?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your web refrence config to include the proper path to your application.
   Your config will look like this:
   `http://someserver/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx`
   Change it to
   `http://someserver/sub1/sub2/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx`
2. `dwsFolder.CreateFolder("Shared Documents/myNewFolder");`